# React is not running in the browser. How can I get this to work?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/thomasmckenna/Downloads/React-Firebase-lesson-58/magic-memory/node_modules/fast-glob/out/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
at Object. (/Users/thomasmckenna/Downloads/React-Firebase-lesson-58/magic-memory/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/globby/index.js:5:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: '/Users/thomasmckenna/Downloads/React-Firebase-lesson-58/magic-memory/node_modules/fast-glob/package.json',
requestPath: 'fast-glob'
}

```
{
  "name": "magic-memory",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `npm install` in the root folder?

Comment: Yeah - I tried running it again and this is what I am getting. 

Thomass-MacBook-Pro:magic-memory thomasmckenna$ npm install

up to date, audited 1991 packages in 3s

157 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

42 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 25 high, 13 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: try to delete your `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install`. Are you running `npm start` to get the project run?

Comment: Tried that, now I an getting this error 

Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '/Users/thomasmckenna/Downloads/React-Firebase-lesson-58/magic-memory/src'

Comment: And yes I am running npm start

Comment: Could you paste your package.json in your question?

Comment: I added the package.json

Comment: You can try adding `"main": "/[YOUR-RELATIVE-PATH]/index.js",` to your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Verify that in your `package.json` file there is an entry for main, usually something like `"main": "dist/cjs"`.

Comment: I did this, and it's opening the browser, but React still not working.

Comment: ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '/Users/thomasmckenna/Downloads/React-Firebase-lesson-58/magic-memory/src'

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at 4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at 8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at 8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at <anonymous>:2:315627
    at <anonymous>:2:324225
    at <anonymous>:2:324229
    at e.onload (index.js:1:1)
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ojnikmlgjpfiogeijjkpeakbedjhjcch/toggle_icon.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Also getting this. Possibly need to redownload devtools